# How to join two tables having two common column values and unioning the rest

Tags: sql

I'd like to combine Table A and Table B at the link below and end up with Table C.  What is the best way to do this in SQL?  I've thought about creating a composite key between the tables for LedgerID + Year doing an inner join and then unioning the left and right only data.  I'm also curious how to avoid duplicating values across rows like Balance = 50.00 ending up in rows for Tires and Windshield.

[image]

Comment: It would be a lot easier for people to help you if you posted the table data as text in your question rather than an image.

Comment: How do you expect to create the first line in Table C? What makes the balance of 50.00 correspond to the tires and not to the windshield?

Comment: There is no correlation other than LedgerID and Year.  They are two separate systems and this is for data comparison.  The 50.00 for example just needing to be rolled up and not duplicated per LedgerID/Year combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a full outer join, joining on LedgerID and Year, using coalesce to show Table B's LedgerID/Year when Table A's is NULL:

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(A.LedgerID, B.LedgerID) as LedgerID,
COALESCE(A.Year, B.Year) as Year,
A.Title,
A.Payment,
B.Balance
FROM "Table A" AS A
FULL OUTER JOIN "Table B" AS B ON (A.LedgerID=B.LedgerID AND A.Year=B.Year)
```

Comment: Appreciate the simple solution.  I would really appreciate understanding why this post was down voted so much.  I'm new to SQL and also couldn't find another post answering this.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks @user1701153, you can find a lot of useful information in the help pages here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 

In general users are looking for questions that are clearly defined and easy to understand, snippets of code showing what work you’ve done, and a clear result your looking to get to. 

In this case I believe there was negativity towards posting a link to a picture of the tables rather than having them on the screen and some confusion around what was required from the last sentence of the question.

Answer (score 0):

--Please try this Query.  Since you have only reference LedgerId and Year, the balance will show 50 for both Tires & Windshield

```
; with cte_Ledger (LedgerId, [year])
AS
(
Select DISTINCT LedgerId, [year]
From tableA
UNION
Select DISTINCT LedgerId, [year]
From tableB
)
select t.LedgerId
        , t.[year]
        , t1.Title
        , T1.Payments
        , t2.Balance
FROM cte_Ledger t
left join tableA t1 on t.LedgerId = t1.LedgerId  and t.[year] = t1.[year]
left join tableB  t2 on t2.LedgerId = t.LedgerId and t2.[year] = t.[year]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think so, Above Queries will not help to get expected result.
some misunderstanding is with requirement.
For ledgerid = 22 and Year = 2017, have 2 records in table-A and 1 with Table-B. But in expecting result, Balance 50(Record of table-B) is exists with matched first row of Table-A only. As per above all logic it will be with 2 Records where ledgerid = 22, Year = 2017 and Title with "**Tires**" & "**Windshield**".

If required same result as mentioned then need to use **recursive CTE** or ranking function with order of **ID** column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution after I loaded the tables, another nested case statement may be need to format out the zero on Ledger 24.

```
Select 
[LedgerID],
[Year],
Case when PayRank = 1 then Title else ''  end as Title,
Case when PayRank = 1 then convert(varchar(20),Payments) else '' end as 
Payments,
Case when BalRank = 1 then convert(varchar(20),Balance) else '' end as 
Balance
from(

SELECT 
  B.[LedgerID]
  ,B.[Year]
  ,Rank()Over(Partition by B.LedgerID,Payments order by 
   B.LedgerID,B.Year,Title) as PayRank
  ,isnull([Title],'') as Title
  ,isnull([Payments],0) as Payments
  ,Rank()Over(Partition by B.LedgerID,B.Year order by 
   B.LedgerID,B.Year,Payments) as BalRank
  ,Balance
   FROM [TableB] B
   left outer join [TableA] A
   on A.LedgerID = B.LedgerID 
    ) Query
   order by LedgerID,Year
```

[image]